# Expo app: How to select different env file when archiving the app locally from Xcode

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native, expo

I am trying to build a react native app using Expo. I have setup three .env file for `development`, `test`, and `production`.

I want to archive the expo app from xcode and select test env. How can I set the NODE_ENV to `test` when archiving?

I am also using the env variable to change the values under app.config.json. I would like those also to change based on env set while archiving